# is there any way to detect bots (like google) with JS?

Tags: javascript, googlebot

i want to create additional page visit analytics (for a/b test) with js. but i need to exclude google bots.

is there any way to exlude bots like google bot in js without any captcha or form validation ?

Comment: Has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084513/detect-search-crawlers-via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

How about the [noindex-meta-tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710)?

In javascript you can check the navigator.userAgent if it matches with any of [those](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en).

Edit: I realize this might not be the answer you were looking for. Is that google analytics? How about goint to Admin > View > View Settings > Bot Filtering
"Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders".