# detect if real browser or any bot or crawler

Tags: jquery, user-agent

Good day everybody, I set a function to get the users country when he/ she visits my website for the first time thanks to a cookie and ajax in jQuery, this function takes about 800ms which provides a wrong page speed stats.
I've did some research but didn't find a way to only execute this function when a real visitor access the website and not any crawler...
I've checked with modernizr but they don't offer the possibility to tell the user agent. I also read about $.browser() but heard it's deprecated...
Do you have any idea how to achieve this?
thanks a lot

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent But userAgent does not ensurely gives you the real browser, because you can edit by yourself the userAgent. All this functionality is deprecated because it's better to target capabilities instead of browser.

Comment: Thanks Marcos for your very fast reply :)
I've already checked that link actually, and would like something that is not deprecated. What if i just want to know if it's a robot or crawler which is visiting the website? there is not easy way to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Search Crawlers via JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084513/detect-search-crawlers-via-javascript)

Comment: That article solves your problem. Good luck!! :)

Comment: These solutions seem to be complicated and not reliable :/ is there any specific feature that can be checked using modernizr which doesn't exist in bots/ crawlers?

Answer (score 0):

Did you find how to manage it?

Be aware that "the user agent string is becoming meaningless and extremely unreliable"* as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897450/if-window-navigator-useragent-is-deprecated-what-should-i-use-instead).

you can also check this library: https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js

There are some interesting features requests:

[Feature request: isBrowser](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/issues/203)

[Feature request: detect crawler](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/issues/156)

Comment: hey @charlesdg, sorry I just saw your message. No i didn't manage it, I ended up by giving up :) but thanks very much for your link, I'll have a look at it ;) Cheers