# If window.navigator.userAgent is deprecated, what should I use instead?

Tags: javascript

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent) says that window.navigator.userAgent is deprecated and should not be used. If I want to collect the users browser and os  data for analytics (not feature detection), what should I use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user agent string is becoming meaningless and extremely unreliable.

You should not use user agent string, rather you should use **feature detection**. If you need to use feature X, test to see if X is available.

But to also answer your question directly, there is no JS alternative.

Answer (score 3):

> Browser identification based on detecting the user agent string is
>   unreliable and is not recommended, as the user agent string is user
>   configurable.
>
> For example:
>
> - In Firefox, you can change the preference
>     general.useragent.override in about:config. Some Firefox extensions do
>     that; however, this only changes the HTTP header that gets sent, and
>     doesn't affect browser detection performed by JavaScript code.
> - Opera 6+ allows users to set the browser identification string via
>     a menu
> - Microsoft Internet Explorer uses the Windows registry
> - Safari and iCab allow users to change the browser user agent
>     string to predefined Internet Explorer or Netscape strings via a
>     menu.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent)

I think, that they are trying **to remove completely** this feature from JavaScript.

**Update:**

> [Object-Oriented JavaScript, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781849693127.do): It's better not to rely
>   on the user agent string, but to use feature sniffing (also called
>   capability detection) instead. The reason for this is that it's hard
>   to keep track of all browsers and their different versions. It's much
>   easier to simply check if the feature you intend to use is indeed
>   available in the user's browser. For example have a look at the
>   following code:
>
> ```
> if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'function') {
>
>   // feature is supported, let's use it
> } 
> else {
>
>   // hmm, this feature is not supported, will have to
>   // think of another way
> }
> ```

Comment: Modernizer already uses feature detection. For example: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/src/prefixedCSSValue.js

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: how do you feature-detect for the need to work around a rendering bug?